# What does the notation \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} mean? Which package arguments into which?

Tags: tables, color

I saw an argument in a file that displayed:

```
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
```

I am a bit confused what is getting parsed into which. It seems that the material in `[]` are usually options for `xcolor`. But in this case they are packages. What does this mean exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that the material in `[]` are usually options for `xcolor`.

That's correct.

> But in this case they are packages.

- I'm not aware of LaTeX packages called `table` or `xcdraw`.
- The option `table` instructs LaTeX to load the `colortbl` package in a way that maximizes its compatibility with the `xcolor` package. Aside: It's a mistake to load the `xcolor` and `colortbl` packages independently.

  For more information, see Table 1 in the user guide of the `xcolor` package.
- Quoting from p. 23 of the package's user guide: If the option `xcdraw` is set, PostScript commands will be used to draw frames and color boxes if the `dvips` driver is set, while PDF code will be used if the document is compiled with pdftex or dvipdfm. The opposite of `xcdraw` is `noxcdraw`; it's the default. If `noxcdraw` is in effect, driver-independent code is used to draw frames and color boxes.